# (tkinter) I'm trying to create a button when clicked a new window will pop out with a label text but an errors shows that it's an invalid syntax

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a mobile phone dialer and my problem is that when I press the "call" button, a new window will appear that shows a text "dialing a number...". Whenever I would run it, a syntax error would always appear. The problem is in the def calling_win(): statement. Can someone fix it?

```
    import tkinter as tk

def btn_press(key):
    numberentry.insert(tk.END, key)
def calling_win():
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.geometry('250x200')
    dial_label = (window, text='Dialing a number...', bg='black', fg='white', font='times new roman', 12, 'bold') .place(padx=30, pady=70)

dialer = tk.Tk()
dialer.title("Mobile Phone Dialer")
dialer.resizable(0,0)

btn_options = dict(padx=10, pady=10, bd= 5, bg='black', fg='white', font=('times new roman', 12, 'bold'))

tk.Button(dialer, btn_options, text=1, command=lambda: btn_press(1)).grid(row=1, column=0)
tk.Button(dialer, btn_options, text=2, command=lambda: btn_press(2)) .grid(row=1, column=1)
tk.Button(dialer, btn_options, text=3, command=lambda: btn_press(3)) .grid(row=1, column=2)
tk.Button(dialer, btn_options, text=4, command=lambda: btn_press(4)) .grid(row=2, column=0)
tk.Button(dialer, btn_options, text=5, command=lambda: btn_press(5)) .grid(row=2, column=1)
tk.Button(dialer, btn_options, text=6, command=lambda: btn_press(6)) .grid(row=2, column=2)
tk.Button(dialer, btn_options, text=7, command=lambda: btn_press(7)) .grid(row=3, column=0)
tk.Button(dialer, btn_options, text=8, command=lambda: btn_press(8)) .grid(row=3, column=1)
tk.Button(dialer, btn_options, text=9, command=lambda: btn_press(9)) .grid(row=3, column=2)
tk.Button(dialer, btn_options, text='*', command=lambda: btn_press("*")) .grid(row=4, column=0)
tk.Button(dialer, btn_options, text=0, command=lambda: btn_press(0)) .grid(row=4, column=1)
tk.Button(dialer, btn_options, text='#', command=lambda: btn_press("#")) .grid(row=4, column=2)
tk.Button(dialer, btn_options, text='Call', command=calling_win) .grid(row=5, column=1)
numberentry = tk.Entry(dialer,bd = 10, width=20,bg='black', fg='white')
numberentry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.N)
dialer.mainloop()
```

Comment: The assignment to `dial_label` inside that function looks like it's missing an actual widget to construct - presumably `tk.Label`.

Comment: thanks I fixed it, the window finally popped out but the text ("Dialing a number") is not there. I just added a tk.Label and then open and close parenthesis on the font=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you forgot the `tk.Label` before so you got the error. Secondly `place` has no `padx` or `pady` so there was a second error. Also you have to put the font in brackets, otherwise tkinter would take the font arguments as other label arguments.

Working Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

def btn_press(key):
    numberentry.insert(tk.END, key)
def calling_win():
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.geometry('250x200')
    dial_label = tk.Label(window, text='Dialing a number...', bg='black', fg='white', font=('times new roman', 12, 'bold')).place(x=30, y=70)

dialer = tk.Tk()
dialer.title("Mobile Phone Dialer")
dialer.resizable(0,0)

btn_options = dict(padx=10, pady=10, bd= 5, bg='black', fg='white', font=('times new roman', 12, 'bold'))

tk.Button(dialer, btn_options, text=1, command=lambda: btn_press(1)).grid(row=1, column=0)
tk.Button(dialer, btn_options, text=2, command=lambda: btn_press(2)) .grid(row=1, column=1)
tk.Button(dialer, btn_options, text=3, command=lambda: btn_press(3)) .grid(row=1, column=2)
tk.Button(dialer, btn_options, text=4, command=lambda: btn_press(4)) .grid(row=2, column=0)
tk.Button(dialer, btn_options, text=5, command=lambda: btn_press(5)) .grid(row=2, column=1)
tk.Button(dialer, btn_options, text=6, command=lambda: btn_press(6)) .grid(row=2, column=2)
tk.Button(dialer, btn_options, text=7, command=lambda: btn_press(7)) .grid(row=3, column=0)
tk.Button(dialer, btn_options, text=8, command=lambda: btn_press(8)) .grid(row=3, column=1)
tk.Button(dialer, btn_options, text=9, command=lambda: btn_press(9)) .grid(row=3, column=2)
tk.Button(dialer, btn_options, text='*', command=lambda: btn_press("*")) .grid(row=4, column=0)
tk.Button(dialer, btn_options, text=0, command=lambda: btn_press(0)) .grid(row=4, column=1)
tk.Button(dialer, btn_options, text='#', command=lambda: btn_press("#")) .grid(row=4, column=2)
tk.Button(dialer, btn_options, text='Call', command=calling_win) .grid(row=5, column=1)
numberentry = tk.Entry(dialer,bd = 10, width=20,bg='black', fg='white')
numberentry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.N)
dialer.mainloop()
```